# Should an answer get deleted if there's already same answer(s)?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

For example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11012943) (10k users only).

The solution is already mentioned in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25181671/5299236), which was posted one year ago. But this one, posted 5 hours ago, and doesn't improve anything.

Should it get deleted because it's useless (I think), or it's fine? If it should, how can I flag it and choose what option to recommend deletion?

Comment: Ugh, those "this is not an answer - to critique or request clarification..." canned comments are a plague upon our house. Almost every time I see it, the answer is doing anything but critiquing or requesting clarification. A [not-so-]rare glimpse into the hellish nightmare of failure that is the review queue.

Comment: Looks like SO worked splendidly and a late superior answer did rise to the top.  Attribution is required, no matter how annoying that is.

Comment: In my opinion? Yes, with gusto. I've even lost out on question acceptance before because someone else answered a question after me with a worse-quality answer that repeated what I said (well, about 5% of what I said) and OP accepted theirs. Based on historical precedence, though, no, people will tell you to just downvote. An exception is probably if the answers were posted within one minute of each other.

Comment: @TylerH: And sometimes, I also see some later answers have more upvotes than the original answer. Oh, about that exception, the funny part is which always confused OP  about accept which answer :P

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can downvote and/or comment. You can also flag for moderator attention with a custom message that the answer doesn't add anything new to already existing answers.

Personally, I would downvote and comment that it doesn't add additional information. If the answerer doesn't add anything relatively soon or comment as to how it is different, then I would flag for a mod and explain *exactly what you think is wrong with it and what you think should be done with it* (in this case, deleted). Or just flag from the beginning if you don't plan on sticking around to see if the answerer responds to a comment.

Since this is coming from the LQ review queue, I would click the "Delete" button and upvote the already existing comment which reflects my thoughts on the "answer".

Comment: What is the advantage of involving a moderator? I would just downvote and vote to delete.

Comment: @Roland It wouldn't be necessary in this situation since it's already in the queue. But I was talking in general if the user doesn't have vote to delete powers then a custom mod flag is the only flag option that makes sense.