# Which review action should be taken for First Answers (not Late Answers) that repeat previously posted answers?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, first-answers

I'm reviewing in the [**First Answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers) queue and I noticed many of them do not really bring new content. They are often the 3rd or 4th answer to a question that already has 2 or 3 acceptable answers; they were posted at a much later time, sometimes to questions with an already accepted answer, and often repeat what is written in other answers.

My options are:

- Accept (Looks OK)
- Edit
- Leave a comment (share feedback)
- Other Action (Raise a flag)

There isn't any flag to mark as a duplicate, or as "not relevant".

What's the best course of action here?

---

Because this question is being marked as a duplicate of [What to do with new answers that just repeat old ones?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326171/2745495), I would like to point out that those answers have already been flagged for review. This question is referring to a **First Answers** review task and maybe a review option could be a solution in this case.

Many comments and the first 2 answers of this question say I should downvote it. While that makes sense, downvoting is not a review action.

**Which review action should be taken here?**

Comment: IMO, there should be a flag reason on answers for “no new helpful information” or something similar. A flag that can be used if an answer only provides unhelpful/already stated info (if an answer has some useful info, you could probably edit to remove the already stated/unhelpful bits).

Comment: I made the same request but for the Late Answer review queue [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411138/10952503)

Comment: Oh, I voted to don't accept the duplicate as I through this post were a feature request, but it's not :/ so it seems to really be a duplicate

Comment: I'm trying to improve SO as a reviewer, and this question was supposed to be focused on review tasks, not just general flagging like the one mentioned above. Those answers were already flagged for review and I have no good alternative besides saying "looks okay".

Comment: also related: [Should an answer get deleted if there's already same answer(s)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315375/839601)

Comment: From the [First Answers help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers), there's a 5th option: _Choose **Other action** if the post needs to be flagged or requires a combination of interactions. **The answer must be flagged first to select this option.**_ It's misleading, but if I'm not mistaken, a downvote or a vote to delete (if you have enough rep) will _also_ activate that option.

Comment: @il_raffa No. You can find an explanation here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425633/how-can-i-vote-for-deletion-of-first-answers-not-late-answers-that-repeat-prev

Answer (score 14):

While downvoting is an option, and you may choose to leave a comment of the "Does this answer bring anything new to this question?" variety, also consider the timing of the new answer with respect to the existing answer.  If the answer was posted within a minute or two of an existing answer with practically the same content, consider *not* downvoting but still leaving the comment.  Don't scare off a new user with a downvote who was just trying to contribute, but got beaten by a short amount of time.

Answer (score 13):

Downvoting is an option too.  If the post isn't useful, then that's what the downvote establishes.

Comment: One would lose to many points if is this is a common occurrence.

Comment: @André:  Yeah, and?  That's kinda the point.  You sacrifice of one rep point to downvote someone's late and terrible answer. Eventually the system stops that person from doing those things, and we achieve world peace.

Comment: It makes sense, but it also sucks that you are reviewing SO to make it better and SO punishes you.

Comment: @André:  You're only losing *one* rep point for a downvote.  That's really small potatoes here, even at < 1k rep.  What's more valuable when reviewing - the reviewer's own reputation or the duty of clarifying if a late answer is good or not?

Comment: Also, a lot of bad answers eventually get deleted; at which point you get your 1 rep back.

Comment: Don't you prevent SO from taking a point by commenting?

Comment: @Rojo:  No.  I don't know what even could've given you that impression.  Commenting and downvoting are distinct and separate things and one has no bearing on the other (unless you downvote to below 50 rep, then  you can't comment)

Comment: @Makoto I downvoted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76010997/excel-sheet-in-python) just now with a comment. It's been 6 minutes and my reputation hasn't changed.

Comment: @Rojo Downvotes on questions do not cost reputation.

Comment: I freely admit I downvote anything I think deserves it regardless of if I think it'll be deleted it not, and I have *plenty* of reputation left. *Not* downvoting for concern of not getting your 1 rep "refunded" doesn't help get bad content shown as *bad content*.

Comment: "One would lose to many points if is this is a common occurrence." - Only if the answer is not eventually deleted.  I routinely downvote contributions I don't find helpful. I have tens of thousands of reputation points.  You have to actively contribute to the community of course. Most late answers in my experience are absolutely horrible quality. Essentially, by not voting on the late answer, you are not helping the community determine if it's helpful or not.

Comment: You should change your answer to "down voting is also a review action" and I will mark it as solved.